# How to source code in this

Tags: javascript

```
var a = ["one", "two", "three"];
 console.log(a.indexOf("two")); // output = 1

 a.indexOf = function(val) {
  return 'HAHAHA';
};

console.log(a.indexOf("two")); // output = 'HAHAHA'
```

What are some ways to restore the functionality of `indexOf`?

```
console.log(a.indexOf("two")); // output = 1
```

Comment: Why do ou want to change the original behaviour ?

Answer (score 1):

You simply re-assign the original function which comes from [`Array.prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

```js
var a = ["one", "two", "three"];
 console.log(a.indexOf("two")); // output = 1

a.indexOf = function(val) {
  return 'HAHAHA';
};

console.log(a.indexOf("two")); // output = 'HAHAHA'

a.indexOf = Array.prototype.indexOf; // re-assign the original function
                                     // which is inherited from Array.prototype.

console.log(a.indexOf("two")); // output = 1
```

Comment: I'd say this is pretty clearly a homework question in which the OP has demonstrated no effort. While your answer is technically correct, the community shouldn't encourage these types of no-effort questions by answering them.